# Unable to pause SKEmitterNode in iOS9

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ios9, particles, skemitternode

I've tried few workarounds, but still I can't pause existing particles on `iOS9`. I am using following technique to pause the scene:

- pause the scene with `self.paused = YES;`
- set custom `globalPause = YES;` variable to control `update:` method execution (because `update:` still runs while scene is paused).

The point is that I don't pause the view, but rather the scene. I don't pause the view, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31471288/3402095).

Here is the code which can reproduce this issue on `iOS9`:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)SKEmitterNode *emitter;

@end

@implementation GameScene


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {


    [self addChild:[self getSpaceDustEmitter]];

}

//No need for this method though :)

-(SKEmitterNode*)getSpaceDustEmitter{

    self.emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"spacedust" ofType:@"sks"]];
     self.emitter .name = @"emitter_spacedust";
    self.emitter .position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),self.frame.size.height);



    return  self.emitter ;
}


@end
```

So, very simple example which works on `iOS8` and not working as expected on `iOS9`. What happens is that even if everything looks that is paused, its not. Existing particles after unpausing move to the point where they should be if the scene was not paused. Also, it looks like that particles keep spawning too, which can produce noticeable lag when unpausing if pause was long...

Here is a screenshot from particle editor:

[image: particle editor]

Anybody have some reasonable explanation ? So far I've tried to explicitly pause the emitter:

```
emitterNode.paused = YES;
```

It didn't worked, and actually this should be done automatically when scene is paused (emitter is added to the scene). Another thing which is tried is to set `emitter.particleSpeed = 0;` as well as `emitter.particleSpeedRange = 0;` and `emitter.particleBirthRate = 0;` but this doesn't affect on already existing particles (which make sense).

And thats it. Not sure if this is a bug, but I am run out of ideas...

Comment: Have you found any workaround for pausing SKEmitterNode?

Comment: @WangYudong Not really... Are you experiencing the same issue ?

Comment: Yes. In iOS 8, everything was OK. And I tried what you said in your post, and got the same results.

Comment: Try removing it from the scene temporarily.

Comment: @Owatch If you remove an emitter from its parent, the existing particles will be removed as well, and that is not what I want. I am trying to stop emitting while an app is in the background, and to continue with emitting when app returns to foreground. Also, I am trying to "pause" existing particles, and to have them continue with their movement, from the point where they left of, on app's return from background.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer but It may just be because we are now in iOS9.3,  is this still an issue for you, because as of 9.3. pause works

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't see your answer.. Did you deleted it?

Comment: Yes i deleted it because I was testing on 9.3, realized this was old

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well you could post it if you are positive that it works. I will accept it. It might be helpful for the readers... I am still on 9.1 and it doesn't work for me... So if you think it is fixed, feel free to post your answer.

Comment: Well the fix is in your question already,  to pause both the node and the scene, but like i said. This is on 9.3,  ill get the 9.1 simulator and see if my particles do not pause

Comment: Does it pause for you on simulator?  it pauses for me on iOS 9.1 iPhone 4s simulator

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It pauses, but the problem is unpausing ... Particles should continue from where they left of, but that is not happening...

Comment: ok I will give it a try hold on

Comment: Looks like the simulation time for particles isn't pausing in 9.1, but the pausing is fixed on 9.3,  I wonder if there is a notification being called to pause it particles

Comment: @Knight0fDragon So it is obviously fixed on 9.3. That is a good news...

Comment: yeah, 9.3 it works fine,  sucks that things like this do not get fixed till the next iteration of iOS,  I tried advancing the simulation time by a negative number,  that doesn't work

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah...At least it works on iOS9.3... I tried many different ways to get this working on iOS9.1 (pausing emitter node, changing its speed, playing with particle birth rate etc etc) and nothing really worked.

Comment: well I know what we can do, get the time that the emitter has been playing before the pause button, then reset the simulator and use `advanceSimulationTime` to reset it on unpause

Comment: Theoretically, that could work... Will try it just for fun as soon as I find time. Personally I am not a fan of those workarounds. If something doesn't work, I skip it. I use something else. Still, it make sense what you are saying and hopefully it might be a nice workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I do not like them either, but apple really does't give a choice, and I am not a fan of forcing people to upgrade their phones or  not use my app (My 6+ is still on iOS 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pause the scene:

```
currentScene.speed = 0
currentScene.paused = true
```

To unpause the scene

```
currentScene.speed = Variables.gameSpeed
currentScene.paused = false
```

Does that work for you?

PS: What iOS version are you working on? I've read about problems with iOS9.1, which seems to be corrected in 9.3, about those emitters.