# Trying to "Pause" Timers and resume them

Tags: ios, swift

Using SpriteKit and Timers in Swift, I am trying to create a feature that will pause the game, and resume with the correct time. I found an awesome source ["Pausing" the Game in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044854/pausing-the-game-in-swift) that showed a system allowing just that. In my code I have the function pauseGame that should allow me to get the current time that the timers were invalidated at

```
func pauseGame(){
    enemyTimer.invalidate()
    enemyTimer2.invalidate()
    changeSpeed.invalidate()
    rubyTimer.invalidate()

    // 0.3 is the original delay time when the timers were created

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeCaptured = calendar.date(byAdding: .nanosecond, value: Int(Int64(0.3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), to: Date())!
    let elapsedTime = timeCaptured.timeIntervalSince(Date)
    let remainingDelay = 0.3 - elapsedTime

}
```

All I have to do is create new timers with the value of remainingDelay, however I get an error on

```
    let elapsedTime = timeCaptured.timeIntervalSince(Date)
```

saying "Cannot convert value of type '(Date).Type' to expected argument type 'Date'"

Any ideas? Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is a class, `Date()` returns an instance of `Date` initialised to "now", you want:

```
let elapsedTime = timeCaptured.timeIntervalSince(Date())
```

Comment: Or simply `let elapsedTime = timeCaptured.timeIntervalSinceNow`.

Comment: Wow can't believe it was that simple! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: But this can't be right. `timeCaptured` is "now" + a few nanoseconds so calculating `elapsedTime` from "now" is just the value added to "now" on the previous line.

Comment: I see, you could also use timeCaptured.timeIntervalSinceNow as it is almost the same thing. Thanks for sharing